# CodeIgniter search box in header

Tags: php, codeigniter

My search box is included in the header.  I want so that when I type any word for a search it grabs results from my database and goes to the search view page with results.  My header is also included on different controllers.

here is my controller

```
public function index()
{ 
    if($this->input->post('submit')) 
    {
        if($this->input->post('search') == '')
        {
            redirect('search');
        }
        $keyword        =   $this->input->post('search');
        $data['rows']   =   $this->search_model->search($keyword);
    }
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('search',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

here is my model

```
function search($keyword)
{
    $this->db->like('title', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('type', $keyword);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('mytable');
    return $query->result();
}
```

here is my view

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="<?php echo base_url();?>search" method="post">
      <div class="input-group cust-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
        <div class="input-group-btn ">
       <button class="btn btn-default cust-searchbtn" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

But when I search for something it redirects to my search page with empty results. I want to do search in the header and send results to my search page where I show the results on that page.

Comment: instead of this if($this->input->post('search') == '') use isset method.

Comment: serach box in header when search a word i send the result to seach.php view page how i send there

Comment: are you getting the search results($data['rows'])?

Comment: Is there a view where `$data['rows']` is getting used?

Comment: @NirajKarmick you dont need to use isset `if($this->input->post('search')){}` will return false if the $_POST key is not available

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{ 
  if(isset($this->input->post('submit'))) 
  {   
    $keyword        =   $this->input->post('search');
    $this->load->model('model_name');
    $data['rows']   =   $this->search_model->search($keyword);
    print_r($data['rows']); //print and check the results are fetching or not---then load it to view.
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('search',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
  }
  else
  {
     redirect('search');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the 'header' view on the 'search' view page on the top. Then your HTML code for search view. And after your finish with your HTML code for 'search' view then load 'footer'.
eg. Your Controller:

```
public function index()
{ 
  if($this->input->post('submit')) 
  {
    if($this->input->post('search') == '')
    {
        redirect('search');
    }
    $keyword        =   $this->input->post('search');
    $data['rows']   =   $this->search_model->search($keyword);
  }

  $this->load->view('search',$data);

}
```

Your View:

```
 <?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>

<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="<?php echo           base_url();?>search" method="post">
  <div class="input-group cust-input">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"   name="search">
    <div class="input-group-btn ">
   <button class="btn btn-default cust-searchbtn" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```